# Parsing text using grep

Tags: regex, linux, parsing, grep

I have a textfile called netlist.txt with the following contents:

```
M1      nmos1

M2      nmos2

P1      pmos1

        M3      nmos3

                M4      nmos4
                        P2      pmos2
```

I want to retrieve only the line which starts with a tab/space and matching all the "M" values that are indented, using regex.

In order to accomplish this I entered the following expression in bash:

```
egrep [:space:]*[M][0-9]+ netlist.txt
```

But it doesn't recognize the space. It retrieves all the lines regardless of having a space or not.
Please give me some advice on this.
Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: You need to place it into a bracket expression: `[[:space:]]`. And if you want to match it one or more times, use `\+`/`+` or `{1,}` after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]M[0-9]' file
```

**Output:**

```
        M3      nmos3
```

`[[:blank:]]` matches either a single space or a single tab at line start. `[[:space:]]` on the other hand matches space or tab or newline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ut in this case you'll get M3 that is spaced by 1 tab and M4 by 2 tabs, but I would like to capture only the one that has one tab, and not both. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works, thanks :-) . But why do you use [[:blank:]] instead of [:blank:] and '' around the command ?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake